# Google Drive with VBnet Express

Tags: vb.net, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I having problems connecting to my Google Drive using VB.net Express 2012.
Does it support it?

```
Imports Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2
Imports Google.Apis.Drive.v2
Imports Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data
Imports Google.Apis.Services
Imports Google.Apis.Util.Store
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Namespace DriveQuickstart
    Class Program
        Shared Scopes As String() = {DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly}
        Shared ApplicationName As String = "Drive API .NET Quickstart"

        Private Shared Sub Main(args As String())
            Dim credential As UserCredential

            Using stream = New FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
                Dim credPath As String = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart")

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, Scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None, New FileDataStore(credPath, True)).Result
                Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString("Credential file saved to: ") & credPath)
            End Using

            ' Create Drive API service.
            Dim service = New DriveService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With { _
                Key .HttpClientInitializer = credential, _
                Key .ApplicationName = ApplicationName _
            })

            ' Define parameters of request.
            Dim listRequest As FilesResource.ListRequest = service.Files.List()
            listRequest.MaxResults = 10

            ' List files.
            Dim files As IList(Of Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File) = listRequest.Execute().Items
            Console.WriteLine("Files:")
            If files IsNot Nothing AndAlso files.Count > 0 Then
                For Each file As var In files
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", file.Title, file.Id)
                Next
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("No files found.")
            End If
            Console.Read()

        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

I ran the Nuget in the console which failed, so I had to copy the DLL's manually to the project and added them as references, which appear to work as the `Imports google.*` is not giving errors anymore, but I get errors in the code.

[image]

Any help?

**Update**

I think the problem might be that I am using vbnet express 2012
as on the https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/dotnet it says:
Prerequisites

To run this quickstart, you'll need:

Visual Studio 2013 or later.

Is there any work around?

**Update2**

I no longer need this code, as I will be using different method
Feel free to answer in case someone else having the same issue

Comment: I have used the .net client library in VS 2010 so that's not true.   Only prerequisite that I am aware of is that it needs to be .net framework 4.0 or 4.5.

Comment: which nugget package did you import exactly?

Comment: All 4 dll files from  portable-net40+sl50+win+wpa81+wp80 (Google.Apis.Auth.dll, Google.Apis.Core.dll,Google.Apis.dll,Google.Apis.Drive.v2.dll)

Comment: This is all you need to import https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Drive.v2/  If the import failed make sure the project is set to .net framework 4.0 or 4.5

Comment: Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

For the var error, that looks like c# .
Replace it with Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File or possibly just File since it is imported.

Replace Filedatastore with Google.Apis.Util.Store.FileDataStore

You are not initializing 'service' correctly.  Again this looks more like c#.
Use something like:
Dim service as new...
See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531244.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
    Imports Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2
    Imports Google.Apis.Drive.v2
    Imports Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data
    Imports Google.Apis.Services
    
    Public Class genel
     Dim Service As DriveService = New DriveService
     Dim UploadRequest As FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload
     Dim wrtr As System.IO.StreamWriter
        Public Sub CreateService(cloudid As String, cloudsecret As String)
    
            Dim ClientId = cloudid
            Dim ClientSecret = cloudsecret
            Dim MyUserCredential As UserCredential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(New ClientSecrets() With {.ClientId = ClientId, .ClientSecret = ClientSecret}, {DriveService.Scope.Drive}, "XXX", CancellationToken.None).Result
            Service = New DriveService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {.HttpClientInitializer = MyUserCredential, .ApplicationName = "XXXXXXX"})
        End Sub
    
    Public Function UploadFile(FilePath As String)
    
            Dim TheFile As New Data.File()
    
            TheFile.Title = IO.Path.GetFileName(FilePath)
            TheFile.Description = "Uploaded File From My Data"
            If sonayir = False Then TheFile.Parents = New List(Of ParentReference) From {New ParentReference() With {.Id = folderID}}
    
            Dim ByteArray As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath)
            Dim Stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream(ByteArray)
    
            Try
                UploadRequest = Service.Files.Insert(TheFile, Stream, TheFile.MimeType)
                UploadRequest.Upload()
    
                Stream.Close()
                Return snc
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return ex.Message
            End Try
        End Function
        Function CreateFolder(folder As String)
            Try
                Dim dosya As File = New File()
                dosya.Title = folder
                dosya.MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
    
                Dim folder_create = Service.Files.Insert(dosya)
                Dim snc = folder_create.Execute()
                Return snc.Id.ToString
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return ex.Message
            End Try
        End Function
        Function DeleteFileorFolder(id As String)
            Dim snc
            Try
                snc = Service.Files.Delete(id).Execute()
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return ex.Message
            End Try
            Return snc
        End Function
        Sub TrashEmpty()
            Try
                Dim mn = Service.Files.EmptyTrash 
                mn.Execute()
            Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Sub
End Class
```

use;

```
Dim gn As New genel
```

**Create Folder**

```
folderId = gn.CreateFolder("FolderName")
```

**File Upload**

```
fileId = gn.UploadFile("FileName")
```

**Delete File Or Folder**

```
gn.DeleteFileorFolder(folderId)
```

**Trash Empty**

```
gn.TrashEmpty()
```